# H2DB - script SQL ON UPDATE in CREATE TABLE request

Tags: sql, maven, h2, sql-maven-plugin

How to do an `ON UPDATE` in a `CREATE TABLE` request in H2 database.

Context:

I'm using the sql-maven-plugin (1.5) to generate a table in an h2 database in my project.

But when I call the script sql, I have a `org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException`.

My script:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEST(
  DATE timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
);
```

Answer (score 6):

H2 doesn't support "ON UPDATE". But I guess you could use a [computed column](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#computed_columns) instead?:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEST(
  DATE timestamp AS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Comment: @Thomas Mueller does this work on UPDATE or only on CREATE?

Comment: This question is quite old, and H2 now supports "ON UPDATE". But if you ask for "IF EXISTS": this is only supported for "CREATE".

Comment: I can't find anything in the docs about using on update. Could you provide a link?

Comment: Here's the git PR describing the change: https://github.com/h2database/h2database/pull/959

Answer (score 4):

H2 supports "ON UPDATE" starting from version 1.4.197 (released 18 Mar 2018) 
Query from question should work just fine, as this one works in our project:

```
last_modified timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

I found that thanks to comments:

[H2DB - script SQL ON UPDATE in CREATE TABLE request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8006855/h2db-script-sql-on-update-in-create-table-request#comment61014058_8007175)

[H2DB - script SQL ON UPDATE in CREATE TABLE request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8006855/h2db-script-sql-on-update-in-create-table-request#comment94008479_8007175)

So please upvote them as well.

Details:

- https://h2database.com/html/changelog.html
- https://github.com/h2database/h2database/pull/959
- https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/219

Comment: Reference please?  I can't find evidence of this searching current H2 docs

Comment: @slashdottir answer updated with some reference links. Please take a look.

Comment: I don't see this fix in 1.4.200

Answer (score 2):

Add to your SQL file:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table (
  `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
  BEFORE UPDATE
  ON my_table
  FOR EACH ROW CALL "org.h2.trigger.UpdatedAtTrigger";
```

Create a Java class and add to your test classpath:

```
package org.h2.trigger;

import java.sql.*;  
import java.time.Instant;
import org.h2.tools.TriggerAdapter;

public class UpdatedAtTrigger extends TriggerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void fire(Connection conn, ResultSet oldRow, ResultSet newRow) throws SQLException {
    newRow.updateTimestamp("updated_at", Timestamp.from(Instant.now()));
  }
}
```